# Windows "copy" with placeholders adds 1 byte to output files

Tags: copy, cmd

Try this:

```
echo Test > a1.txt
copy a1.txt b.txt
copy a?.txt c.txt
```

File c.txt will be 1 byte larger that b.txt. Why is that?

Workaround:

```
for %i in (a?.txt) do copy %i d.txt
```

d.txt will have the correct size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have provided multiple source files due to wild-card `?` (even if there is only one matching file) and a singe destination file, which lets `copy` append the source files. In this mode, `copy` treats the source and destination files as ASCII text files (as if you would have given the `/A` switch), so it appends the end-of-file (EOF) character (code 26 dec. = 0x1A hex.) and truncates every source file at the (first) EOF character. Adding the `/B` switch prevents that:

```vb
copy /B a?.txt c.txt
```

---

Regard that the position of the switches `/A` and `/B` matters, so you can:

- define the way how to treat the files globally, when providing the switches before the first file specification:

  ```vb
  rem // Treat all files as binary ones:
  copy /B a.txt + b.txt c.txt
  ```
- alter the way individually:

  ```vb
  rem /* Treat `a.txt` as ASCII text file (default for multiple sources),
  rem    then treat `b.txt` and `c.txt` as binary files: */
  copy a.txt + b.txt /B c.txt
  ```

Comment: This explanation sounds plausible. Do you have any idea *why* "`copy` treats the destination file as an ASCII text file" when using a wild-card? (I guess because appending non-text files is the much rarer use-case.) Anyway, closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41779488/880783

Comment: For the reason why I guess you have to consult the developers of MS-DOS... ;-) Anyway, for single files defaulting to binary mode makes sense; perhaps the EOF char. was used in FAT file systems, so special handling of it when combining multiple source files makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

`copy /B a?.txt c.txt` seems to work. B is for binary, so no end of file character is added.