# Why does BASIC append 0x1a to the end of a file?

Tags: basic

I'm attempting to transfer files to an old PCjr via null modem serial cable. I cobbled up a quick BASIC script to read data from a serial port and write it to a file, but I've discovered every file I save has an extra byte, 0x1a, at the end.

It seems to be caused by the `CLOSE` statement, as even `OPEN`ing and `CLOSE`ing a file without writing anything results in a one-byte file.

I don't want a SUB character at the end of my files, especially binary ones! Is there an alternate way of writing files that prevents this behavior?

(Using the excellent ["PC-BASIC"](https://robhagemans.github.io/pcbasic/) in a Lubuntu VM for demonstration, but this seems to be a "thing" in all variants of BASIC)

```
josh2112@jf334-lubuntu-vm:~$ pcbasic -b
PC-BASIC 2.0.0                                                                  
(C) Copyright 2013--2018 Rob Hagemans.                                          
60300 Bytes free                                                                
Ok                                                                              
OPEN "O",#1,"TEST.TXT":PRINT#1,"hello world";:CLOSE:SYSTEM                      
josh2112@jf334-lubuntu-vm:~$ xxd TEST.TXT 
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f20 776f 726c 641a            hello world.
```

Comment: `CHR$(&H1A)` is the `EOF` (End Of File) character. The author(?) of PC-BASIC had this to say about adding support for omitting EOF characters: _"Sorry, I have no plans to extend the syntax of PC-BASIC or the OPEN statement beyond the capabilities of GW-BASIC - I am focussing on maximising compatibility for existing programs.

Perhaps you could use a shell script (or Python, or JS itself) to remove the &h1A end-of-file marker from the files your program generates?"_

Comment: Nor would I want PC-BASIC to deviate from GW-BASIC; I just used it to demonstrate. My question is, is there a way in the BASIC language to work around that behavior that I might apply to the code on my PCjr? Python and JavaScript are certainly not going to run there!

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699976/batch-script-to-merge-files-without-hex-char-1a-at-the-end. The post discusses how DOS handles copying data with the EOF indicator and how the flags work. Could you batch the copying the files with the switches indicated?

Comment: @DougDawson sounds like it may work, tonight I'll see if the version of DOS on the PCjr (2.10) supports those switches on its copy command.

Comment: @DougDawson works!  If you make an answer out of your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You could open the for binary and write each character one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

[Batch script to merge files without Hex char 1A at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699976/batch-script-to-merge-files-without-hex-char-1a-at-the-end)

The post discusses how DOS handles copying data with the EOF indicator and how the flags work. Could you batch the copying the files with the switches indicated?

**EDIT by question author**: Yes, this is it. The specific command needed is
`copy src.bin /a dest.bin /b`. This strips off the EOF byte from the end of the file. This is even supported way back in DOS 2.10! Annoying that I have to run this extra step after using my BASIC program to save the file, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this in GW-BASIC is a bit more involved because you have to open the file in binary mode.  The only GW-BASIC file mode that does this is `RANDOM`.  Which allows random access to records of a given length.

One drawback is that this mode doesn't truncate the opened file if it already exists.  So you must delete the file.  But also dealing with the possibility that there was no file with that name.  A short way to do that is to create it in text mode before deleting it.

Then you open the file in `RANDOM` mode with a record length of 1 and write each character/byte as a record to that file.

Here's the code:

```
10 FILENAME$="test.txt"
20 'Delete any old content.
30 OPEN FILENAME$ FOR OUTPUT AS #1:CLOSE 1:KILL FILENAME$
40 'Open file in random mode with record length of 1 and assign a field to C$.
50 OPEN FILENAME$ FOR RANDOM AS #1 LEN=1:FIELD #1,1 AS C$
60 TEXT$="Hello, World!"+CHR$(13)
70 'Now PUT each character/byte into the file one by one.
80 FOR I%=1 TO LEN(TEXT$):LSET C$=MID$(TEXT$,I%,1):PUT #1:NEXT
90 CLOSE 1
```

This produces a 14 byte long file without the EOF character.

I've tested this with GW-BASIC.  PC-BASIC 2.0.4 seems to have a bug there; it ignores the record length and falls back to the default of 128 bytes per record, producing a 14×128=1792 bytes long file with 127 zero bytes after each character.

Answer (score 0):

Function to write a string to a data output file without trailing eof char:

```
OPEN "B", #1, "TEST.TXT"
X$ = "hello world"
FOR X = 1 TO LEN(X$)
    Z$ = MID$(X$, X, 1)
    PUT #1, X, Z$
NEXT
```

Comment: Never heard of a "B" switch, and my PCjr from 1983 has never heard of it either.

Comment: Hmm, if that's the case then an eof will always be appended.